# Fail an MSTest from background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, mstest, assert

I have an integration test that uses multiple threads. I'd like any thread to be able to fail the test (and tear down the rest). However, an exception on a background thread causes MSTest to fail - you simply get an error:

> The agent process was stopped while the test was running

I suppose I could catch any exceptions on background threads, and wake up the main thread to fail the test, but is there an easier/more elegant way?

Comment: You'll have to block the "main" thread (the test runner thread) until the background thread has completed--then fail with `Assert` on the test runner thread.  if you don't block this thread, the runner can exit before you background thread is completed.  If you provide an example of what you've tried, someone can probably give you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to use different threads (and not a `ThreadPool` one) you could use a `Task` with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option which will create a dedicated thread for that Task (and not one from the `ThreadPool`). Then you can examine `IsFaulted` and `Exception` properties of that Task. This is a simple code for that:

```
var task = new Task(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
task.Start();
try { task.Wait(); }
catch { }

if (task.IsFaulted)
{
    // do something about the exception
    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception);
}
```